# Flex. Как выровнять класс по правому краю?

Tags: html, css, pug

```
.iqdropdown-buttons
  button.iqdropdown-button_clean очистить
  button.iqdropdown-button_apply применить
```

```
.iqdropdown-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

так всё отображается правильно, но если добавить класс .display-none { display: none; } вот так

```
.iqdropdown-buttons
  button.iqdropdown-button_clean .display-none очистить
  button.iqdropdown-button_apply применить
```

то кнопка "применить" перемещается к левому краю, на место кнопки "очистить".

Как сделать чтобы она оставалась на месте ?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tostershmoster/pen/xxEGvwJ?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
.display-none { 
   display: none; 
}
```

поставьте

```
.display-none {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

или

```
.display-none {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: при opacity: 0; можно же будет нажать на кнопку

Comment: @Divatoz  тогда впишите еще `{ pointer-events: none; }`. Тогда будет нельзя нажать.

Answer (score 0):

Заходим в документацию и читаем, что делает `.display-none`
http://htmlbook.ru/css/display

> Временно удаляет элемент из документа. Занимаемое им место не
> резервируется и веб-страница формируется так, словно элемента и не
> было. Изменить значение и сделать вновь видимым элемент можно с
> помощью скриптов, обращаясь к свойствам через объектную модель. В этом
> случае происходит переформатирование данных на странице с учетом вновь
> добавленного элемента.

Очевидно, проблема из-за него. А для решения проблемы неплохо было бы прикрепить html код и CSS, чтобы воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: [codepen](https://codepen.io/tostershmoster/pen/xxEGvwJ?editors=1100)